# Maven not running test in class files suffixed with "Tester"

Tags: java, maven, junit4

`mvn clean install` and `mvn test` commands will run all tests on files named `SomethingTest.java` just fine but won't run tests in files named `SomethingTester.java`

According to the [docs for the maven surefire plugin](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html) it should run tests that match the `**/Test*.java` pattern by default, is there a step that I am missing to make maven recognize tests following this pattern?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation you linked to says:

> By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:
>
> - "**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
> - "**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
> - "**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".

Your class doesn't match any of those patterns:

- it doesn't start by Test
- it doesn't end by Test
- it doesn't end by TestCase

The doc then says:

> If the test classes do not follow any of these naming conventions, then configure Surefire Plugin and specify the tests you want to include.

a few lines later, there is an explanation and an example showing how to specify an include pattern.

> An include/exclude pattern can be an ant-style path expression, but regular expressions are also supported through this syntax:
>
> [...]

Comment: lmao.. i'm an idiot... thank you... i need it to run `**/*Test*.java`

Answer (score 3):

Realized that I actually needed to run tests following the `**/*Test*.java` pattern

which I did by adding the following to my `pom.xml`

```
<project>
    [...]
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.18.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test*.java</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    [...]
</project>
```